Remix-Run V2: Is it possible to make the root route ('/') automatically resolve to a dynamic route?
Remix-run/react: @2.9.2
Whenever a user visits my web page, such as "https://domainname.com", I would like it to automatically resolve to "https://domainname.com/shop/all"
I have a dynamic route under my app/routes folder: shop.$shopFilter, and two links in my root.tsx JSX:
<ul>
  <li>
    <Link to={'/shop/all'}>shop all</Link>
  </li>
  <li>
    <Link to={'/shop/clothes'}>shop clothes</Link>
  </li>
</ul>

Is it possible to force the root route to resolve to the "/shop/all" dynamic route, and thus execute the logic within that component as if the user clicked on my link to the "/shop/all" route in remix-run?

The simplest way is to create an index route that redirects to the correct URL.
// routes/_.index.tsx
import { redirect } from '@remix-run/node'

export const loader = () => redirect('/shop/all')

As soon as the user visits https://domainname.com it will redirect to https://domainname.com/shop/all
